# Scanner infinite loop causes browser to hang

Tags: java, http, loops, browser

I have really been trying to work out this problem for about an hour now, but I simply cannot find a solution for it.

Look at the below code:

```
public void handleRequest() throws IOException {
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    }

    out.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\ntest");
    out.flush();
}
```

If I connect my browser (Chrome) to *localhost*, it will just hang forever. I have to press escape (force it to stop requesting) to actually receive all of the line of input derived from it's request.

The idea is very simple; If the request has a next line, just get taking that line until there's nothing left, and then send the 200 OK response. But this doesn't work at all.

EDIT:

@Zutty asked where in was located:

```
public class HttpServer {
public static final int PORT = 80;
public static final int BACKLOG = 1;
public static final String ROOT_CATALOG = "C:/HttpServer/";

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket client;
private Scanner in;
private PrintWriter out;

private FileInputStream fstream;
private final String TWOHUNDRED = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                                + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                                + "\r\n";

public HttpServer() throws IOException {
    server = new ServerSocket(PORT, BACKLOG);
}

public Socket accept() throws IOException {
    client = server.accept();
    in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
    out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

    return client;
}
```

And in main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer();

        while(true) {
            try(Socket client = server.accept()) {
                server.handleRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `in` and where is it set?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Is this code being run in an applet?

Comment: I think it never exit because it never finds and `EOF`. You should search for `\r\n\r\n` to know where the request ends.

Comment: @DavideBerra I've tried to break the while loop when nextLine.equals("\r\n\r\n"); but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I think that's because the line breaks at the first \r\n. You should parse the content with another method

Comment: @DavideBerra I get what you're saying, but the loop still continued to hang even if I tried to break it with \r\n\r\n. In that case, it should've stopped right after the very first line. But it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTTP you should *always* send the Content-Length header. Then the receiving end knows exactly how many bytes of content to read. This avoids all the messy "read until EOF" or "Until I find \r\n\r\n" issues.